# solve $x' = t^\alpha +x^\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following ode for some  non zero $\alpha \beta$ :

$x' = t^\alpha + x^\beta$. I don't have any initial conditions.

I am not sure how to proceed with this ,I tried doing$ x=y^m$ to get $x'=my^(m-1) y'$ but I don know if it helps.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll get a closed-form solution in general.  Maple doesn't find one.  Even in the special case $\alpha=2, \beta=3$ it doesn't find one.  Nor does Wolfram Alpha.

Of course if $\beta = 1$ you have a linear equation.
If $\beta = 2$ a solution can be found in terms of Bessel functions.